# Spring MVC + AngularJS 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

The question is very simple and I know it was answered in many other question but none worked for me. Using Spring MVC and AngularJS I am getting AngularJS 415 Unsupported Media Type !

I tried setting angular header to application/json
I tried with `@Consumes` annotation on Server Side
I tried with `consumes ="application/json"`
I tired with `consumes ="application/application/json;charset=UTF-8'`
I tried with `consumes ={"application/json","application/xml"}`
I also tried to setup produces   property.

I tried explicitly setting the hear content type on the client to match exactly the one on the server but,  NOTHING WORKED !
here are related questions that none actually helped ! 
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950346/angularjs-spring-415-unsupported-media-type)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950346/angularjs-spring-415-unsupported-media-type) 
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009320/415-unsupported-media-type-with-spring-mvc-and-rest-service)

Here is my Controller

```
/**
 * Created by adelin.ghanayem@gmail.com
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/administration/places")
public class PlacesController {

    private PlacesService service;

    @Autowired
    public PlacesController(PlacesService service) {

        this.service = service;

    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public String newPlace(@RequestBody Place places) {

        String id = service.addNewPlace(places);

        return "/administration/places/" + id;

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Place getById(@PathVariable String id) {

        return new Place();

    }


}
```

And my AngularJS controller

```
function NewPlacesController(scope, http) {


    scope.place = {};

    scope.add = function () {

        http.post(URLS.addNewPlace, scope.place,{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).success(function (value) {

            console.log("got it !");

        }).error(function (value) {
            console.log("CUR!");
        });

    }
}

NewPlacesController['$inject'] = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

Comment: What does your request look like? What does your method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, produces={"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
public String newPlace(@RequestBody Place places) {

    String id = service.addNewPlace(places);

    return "/administration/places/" + id;

}
```

And make sure you included Jackson Databind library.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the content-type in your angular code. You may need to explicitly set it. Also look at your Spring MVC implementation. You can use the "REST Console" app in chrome to test your api to make sure it works the way you believe it should.

Answer (score 1):

add in your pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to this answer.  What's a pom?  Why does this need to be added?

Comment: pom.xml is a used for a project maven. Maven is a "program" to help you to build a java/J2EE app. Difficult at the beginning, but after , you can build quickly a web apps.

Comment: here a tutorial about maven :
http://www.denofprogramming.com/apache-maven-tutorial-pom/